# C# Mysql create a table name with spaces

Tags: c#, mysql, space, create-table

I have searched quite a bit for this without luck, my question is simple, I have a class that looks like this:

```
    public static void Mysql_CreateTable(string tableSegment, string ConString)
    {
        string strCreate = "CREATE TABLE " + tableSegment + " (CVR text,Navn text, Firma text, Nummer text, Addresse text, Postnr text, Bynavn text, Noter text, Email text, LastCallDato text, NextCallDato text, CallStatus text, MailSendt text, UniqueID text);";
        using (MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(ConString))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(strCreate, conDatabase))
            {
                conDatabase.Open();
                cmdDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conDatabase.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

When tableSegment contains a space like this "table 1" I get a Mysql error saying:

you have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax......

So, what am I doing wrong? Why can't I enter space into the table name?

Comment: I assume you have to determine where the name starts and where it ends. You should put the name into (double)-quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
string strCreate = "CREATE TABLE `" + tableSegment + "` (CVR..............
```

Comment: I was just testing the code, it works, but how would the string look like if I need to delete the table with space in the table name?

Comment: same as above. to work with table name with space, you need to put the table name in ` sign. So it will be something `string strCreate = "DELETE FROM `" + tableSegment + "`..............`